# Politely giving a reason for coming to the office late

Tags: politeness, reason

How does one tell his manager that he is late because of a traffic jam?
Is it okay to say:

> すみません、交通渋滞できから遅きます。

Comment: 渋滞で遅刻になりました。[Profusely Bow]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are in traffic jam, you would call to say

> すみません、渋滞で遅れます。

or more formally

> 申し訳ありません。渋滞で遅れてしまいます。

When you have gotten there, you would tell your manager in the past tense

> すみません、渋滞で遅れました。

or more formally

> 申し訳ありません。渋滞で遅れてしまいました。